# Pygame sprite won't move with "event.type KEYDOWN"

Tags: python, sprite, pygame

The Ball() class will not get the information from the KEYDOWN/KEYUP in "for event in pygame.event.get()" so the ball will not move across the screen. It displays at the right coordinates but fails to move, which confuses me. Here is the code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
darkBlue = (0,0,128)
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
pink = (255,200,200)

background = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,521),0,32)

pygame.display.set_caption('V1.1')
s = 0 #s and s2 for displaying score later on
s2 = 0

class Ball():
    def __init__(self):
        ball = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
        ball.image = pygame.image.load('red_ball.png').convert()
        ball.rect = ball.image.get_rect()
        ball.image.set_colorkey((white))
        screen.blit(ball.image,(x,y))
        pygame.display.update()
    def update(self):
        if x > 640:
            x = 0
        if x < 0:
            x = 640

def main():
    while 1:
        screen.blit(background, (0,0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        Ball()
        pygame.display.update()


x,y = 285, 430
m_x, m_y = 0,0
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_a:
            m_x = -4
            s+=1
        elif event.key == K_d:
            m_x = +4
            s2+=1
    elif event.type == KEYUP:
        if event.key == K_a:
            m_x = 0
        elif event.key == K_d:
            m_x = 0
x+= m_x
y+= m_y


main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Your main loop doesn't make much sense. The update code for the position and event checking is done once (and only once) before the main loop begins. This needs to be inside the ball class, and called from the main loop regularly:

```
def main():
    ball = Ball() #You only want one instance of the ball.
    while True: #More Pythonic to use 'True' rather than 1. You are not testing a number, you are testing a truth.
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            else:
                ball.handle_event(event) #Pass the event onto the ball to deal with.
        ball.update() #Update the ball.
        pygame.display.update()
```

This is closer to the structure you want. Now move your event handling and position updating code into the ball class.

You want to handle the events the ball manages within that class - this is the aim of object orientation. Try to think of it as a flow of data through the system. First your main loop takes the input and handles it, if it doesn't (or the data might be used elsewhere too) it passes that input on to other objects as needed, and tells the other objects to update themselves.

You also only want to create one instance of the ball, otherwise it will not keep it's values. In your example you are recreating it every time.

Answer (score 0):

kindly try to add "pygame.KEYDOWN" & "pygame.KEYUP" as you were calling pygame keypress & release function

Here's the example:

`if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:`

```
    if event.key == K_a:
        m_x = -4
        s+=1
    elif event.key == K_d:
        m_x = +4
        s2+=1.......
```

`elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:`

```
    if event.key == K_a:
        m_x = 0
    elif event.key == K_d:
        m_x = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Event.Key event is not even in the main loop. If you put your code like this:

```
    while 1:
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_a:
                m_x = -4
                s+=1
            elif event.key == K_d:
                m_x = +4
                s2+=1
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_a:
                m_x = 0
            elif event.key == K_d:
                m_x = 0
```

That should make your program run. You should remember to put the pygame. phrase in front of the KEYDOWN and KEYUP. That should allow the code to do the event.type == KEYDOWN and event.type == KEYUP (including the way I think you should put your code). Hope this helps you!